# Why my JTextField not being filled

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I would like to know why JTextField are not being filled, and that put the System.out.println test are completed correctly? Could someone could help me clarify this doubt?
My method.:

```
protected void ApresentaGrupos(List<GrupoBean> grupos) {  
String codigo = "";  
        String grupo = "";  
        for (GrupoBean g : grupos) {  
            codigo = g.getCodigo().toString().trim();  
            grupo = g.getGrupo();  

            System.out.println("" + g.getCodigo().toString().trim()); // TEST
            System.out.println("" + g.getGrupo().toUpperCase()); // TEST
        }  
        this.habilitaCampos();  
        txtCodigo.setText("TEST"); // nor that message is being shown  
        txtGrupo.setText(grupo);  
        System.out.println("teste" + codigo);  
        System.out.println("teste" + grupo);
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.n. described issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not identifiable in the code you've posted, and so we can only guess. Perhaps your txtCodigo and txtGrupo JTextFields are not the same as the ones that are being displayed. This can happen in a variety of situations, often if there is misuse of inheritance. Does this class inherit from another class of yours by chance?

Also this doesn't make sense:

```
    for (GrupoBean g : grupos) {  
        codigo = g.getCodigo().toString().trim();  
        grupo = g.getGrupo();  
    }  
    txtGrupo.setText(grupo);
```

Since it appears that only the last GrupoBean in the grupos collection will have a chance of being displayed in your GUI.

As per mKorbel: For better help though, consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: the operation of the code is so I have the frames, a cadastre and other research. User when you double-click the table's frame search, I get the value of the code shown in the registration table and phaco research at the bank, fill the list with data fields and I want to present the other frame. The data are coming, the problem and that he are not presented in the JTextField, the more you put in a system.out. println's right. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: @galla.info: your posts still don't tell us the structure of your program or what's wrong. You need to show more, and again, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

It might be Possible that after adding `txtCodigo` to the `container`,  you reconstructed the `txtCodigo` and now putting texts in that newly constructed `JTextArea`. So the value that you are putting in txtCodigo is not reflecting in the actual `JTextArea` added in the container.
For Example Consider the Code Give below:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class  DoubleConstruction extends JFrame
{
    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    public DoubleConstruction()
    {
        super("JTextArea Demo");
    }
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        getContentPane().add(field);
        field.setText("Java");
        field = new JTextField(20);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setText()
    {
        field.setText("J2EE");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                DoubleConstruction dc = new DoubleConstruction();
                dc.prepareAndShowGUI();
                dc.setText();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In method `prepareAndShowGUI()` after adding field to the `ContentPane` , field is reconstructed. And within `main` method although I have changed the content of field to "J2EE" but the `JTextField` shown in `JFrame` is still showing "Java".
These are the silly mistakes but chances of occurrence of such mistakes are not null..